# Winforms WebView2 with fixed runtime not working from shared folder

Tags: c#, winforms, webview2

I'm using a fixed version of WebView2 runtime like described in [WebView2 working without WebView2 Runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68388942/webview2-working-without-webview2-runtime/69251385#69251385).

When I save this fixed runtime folder on my local machine it works fine. But as soon as I try to access the exact same folder on a shared folder/server it does not work. Any ideas?

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.InitWeb();
    }

    public async void InitWeb()
    {

        var webEnv = await CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync(@"\\SharedFolder\FixedVersionFolder", Path.GetTempPath());
        //var webEnv = await CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync(@"C:\FixedVersionFolder", Path.GetTempPath());
        await this.webView21.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(webEnv);

        webView21.Source = new Uri("https://www.microsoft.com");
    }
```

In this case the webview does not show but if I replace the webEnv init line with the commented one, which points to my local folder it works just fine. I have tried multiple shared folders including creating one on my computer and it does not work.

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66551736/10024425 or try using [CreationProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.wpf.corewebview2creationproperties?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.1264.42). ex: `webView21.CreationProperties = new CoreWebView2CreationProperties() { UserDataFolder = userDataFolder };`  (you'll need to specify `BrowserExecutableFolder`) prior to setting Source .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that worked for me was setting the WEBVIEW2_ADDITIONAL_BROWSER_ARGUMENTS to --no-sandbox before the initialization of webview. I'm aware that this can cause some security risk, so use at your own risk.

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("WEBVIEW2_ADDITIONAL_BROWSER_ARGUMENTS", "--no-sandbox");
```